# ASP.Net Core API won't work using SSL browser throws ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: visual-studio, api, asp.net-core, ssl, iis

I'm building an API in Visual Studio using ASP.NET Core Web Application, but since a couple of days ago it doesn't work anymore. When I run the API from Visual Studio using IIS Express I get an error in the browser: "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET".

The application does work when I disable SSL, but it should (and before did) work with SSL enabled.

Things I've tried:

- Change port (within the correct range)
- Delete localhost certificate and repair Visual Studio, prompting the creation of a new SSL certificate
- Deleted the .VS file and restarted VS in administrator mode
- Delete applicationhost.config and restarted VS in administrator mode
- Created a fresh application with a working pre build WeatherAPI, but that has the same problem aswel
- Ran SSL Diagnostics using Jexus and got the following

> ```
> System Time: 18/06/2020 14:40:58
>
> Processor Architecture: AMD64
>
> OS: Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.18363.0
>
> Server Type: IIS Express
>
> SERVER SSL PROTOCOLS
>
> PCT 1.0:
>
> PCT 1.0 is not secure. OS default is used. You might explicitly disable it via registry.
>
> SSL 2.0: 
>
> SSL 2.0 is not secure. OS default is used. You might explicitly disable it via registry.
>
> SSL 3.0: 
>
> SSL 3.0 is not secure. OS default is used. You might explicitly disable it via registry.
>
> TLS 1.0: 
>
> TLS 1.0 is not secure. OS default is used. You might explicitly disable it via registry.
>
> TLS 1.1: 
>
> TLS 1.1 is not secure. OS default is used. You might explicitly disable it via registry.
>
> TLS 1.2: 
>
> SChannel EventLogging: 1 (hex)
>
> To tune TLS related settings, please follow https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/187498 or try out IIS Crypto from https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/.
>
> Microsoft documentation on cipher suites can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secauthn/cipher-suites-in-schannel.
>
> -----
> [W3SVC/1]
> ServerComment  : WebSite1
> ServerAutoStart: True
> ServerState    : Stopped
>
> BINDING: http *:8080:localhost
> ```

For what it's worth I've also checked for the subkeys through Regedit, but couldn't find the subkeys inside `HKey_Local_Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders \SCHANNEL\Protocols\`

I am completely at a loss what it could be

Edit: Tried it on another PC, on which it seems to work properly

Comment: You might try to run some diagnostics, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html Probably the certificate mapping in HTTP API has been removed.

Comment: Which browser and version are you using?

Comment: @LexLi thanks for your comment, I did this and added the information to the main question. To be honest, I didn't really know what the result meant exactly so I went to the websites it recommended and tried to locate the subkeys inside Protocols through regedit, but there weren't any.

Comment: @Nenad Thanks for your comment as well. I use Chrome as my standard browser (Version 83.0.4103.106) but the same kind of error occurs in FireFox, Edge and Opera.

Comment: As the report revealed, there is only a site with HTTP binding. No doubt HTTPS won't work at all. I doubt if you have configured the project in Visual Studio properly, as that should generate the HTTPS binding.

Answer (score 2):

According to the binding configuration from the report, there is no https binding in your project.

> BINDING: http *:8080:localhost

Please ensure you checked the option of configuring HTTPS binding while creating the AspDotNET CoreAPI project.
[image]
This will add additional code snippets to `Startup.cs` file.

```
//Adding middlewares for redirecting HTTP request to HTTPS
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

And additional HTTPS binding configuration in `launchSettings.json` file.
[image]
Besides, most of the browsers start to support TLS1.2 only, please ensure that TLS1.2 is not disabled.
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: Thanks for responding! My project has been set up exactly as you described, but I also created a new project following your steps, just for good measure. Problem sadly persists. I tried running the project on a different computer than mine, and there my project seems to work properly using HTTPS, so there is most likely a problem with my PC / VS I guess. (I will add it to the question aswell)

Comment: Do the other website in your PC work over https properly? Besides, when hosting the WebAPI project in IIS express, is there an https binding in `launchSettings` and a binding configuration in the IIS Express tray icon in the lower right corner?